# Where can I find Ubuntu 14.04 core images?

Tags: ubuntu-core

All the internet points me to [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04.4/release/) (including the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes)) but the link is broken. Anyone knows where to find it?

Comment: Good question! I see Vivid and Xenial (but no Trusty) files here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/

Answer (score 4):

The new all-snap Ubuntu Core does not exist for 14.04, because much of the technology that has gone into it was only recently mature.

We are also still finalising the Ubuntu Core 16 release now that classic 16.04 LTS is out. If you are interested in snaps and Ubuntu Core, my suggestion is to start with 16.04 LTS classic and learn snapcraft and the snap tools. Ubuntu Core 16 will be out shortly, and its all the same libraries and kernel etc, just pure-snap from start to finish.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a sunxi ARM system (mk802) and building an image with 16.04 core daily didn't work for me on the first try, probably because I'm not so familiar with snappy. I'll try again sometime after getting familiar with classic as you suggested. In any case, aren't 12.04 and 14.04 still supported? Also, all the 404 links on the documentation linking to Ubuntu Core images should probably be fixed.